# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'python_implementation' running pip

Tags: python, cygwin, pip

I installed Cygwin with Python set-up tools.  When I try to run pip install `awscli` I get the following error:

```
$ pip install awscli
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.5.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.log import logger
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.5.egg/pip/log.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import colorama, pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.5.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 1112, in <module>
    class MarkerEvaluation(object):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.5.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 1120, in MarkerEvaluation
    'python_implementation': platform.python_implementation,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'python_implementation'
```

Am I missing something in my path or is my Python implementation hosed?

Comment: Try to download the module from [github](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) and run `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 18):

Do you have a folder called "/platform" inside your python app?

If you do, it will scope-shadow the native python "platform" module. When modules you're using try to get information about the system, they'll get a null object back. This will often cause errors like:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'`

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'machine'`

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'python_implementation'`

Simply rename the "/platform" folder to something else to resolve the problem.

Comment: I had a file named platform and this helped me. Thanks !

Comment: Crazy.  My script was called platform.py because that was a very reasonable name for what I was creating; but apparently that name is verboten.

Comment: Life saved. Thank you

Comment: Damn, that's crazy. This was a nightmare to debug, but yes, do not name your stuff "platform".

Answer (score 7):

Re-installing `pip` might fix it, try it using [`easy_install`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools):

`sudo easy_install pip`

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a folder called "/platform" inside your python app? GOT THE POINT!  I remove my own platform.py, it still not work. later i remove the remained platform.pyc ,it worked!

Comment: So, are you recommending they remove platform.pyc?

Comment: yes, when running ”import platform“, it first of all find platform.pyc, if exists, it will run directly. if not, it will compile and generate platform.pyc and then run it.  so if you don't want to overwrite python's platform.py you should clear all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what others have posted, I got the same error from having a platform.py file (rather than directory). I renamed it and the error went.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when my .virtualenvs folder for a linux (fedora) system was symlinked to a Network shared drive (on a Windows server). Upgrading the system pip

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

And then creating a new ~/.virtualenvs/ locally with a fresh virtualenv did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add another name to the list: I had a script named `profile.py` in the startup directory that was causing the same problem.

Strangely enough, I thought I *might* have had a file called `platform.py` in the directory. I use Python in the manufacture of turbine blades, which have features we call 'platforms'. They also have a 'profile' (the airfoil leading edge profile, to be exact), and when I saw `profile.py` a light bulb went off, as I was aware of Python's 'profile' module from the Standard Library.

Funny how this never came up before - I've been using IPython since ~Python2.7.9, and there wasn't even a problem back in the 3.6 days (I'm upgrading to 3.8.6).