# Python kernel dies on Jupyter Notebook with tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, conda

I installed tensorflow 2 on my mac using conda according [these](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/) instructions:

```
conda create -n tf2 tensorflow
```

Then I installed ipykernel to add this new environment to my jupyter notebook kernels as follows:

```
conda activate tf2
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=tf2
```

That seemed to work well, I am able to see my **tf2** environment on my jupyter notebook kernels.

Then I tried to run the simple MNIST [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner) to check if all was working properly and I when I execute this line of code:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

The kernel of my jupyter notebook dies without more information.

[image: dead kernel]

I executed the same code on my terminal via **python mnist_test.py** and also via **ipython** (command by command) and I don't have any issues, which let's me assume that my tensorflow 2 is correctly installed on my conda environment.

Any ideas on what went wrong during the install?

Versions:

```
python==3.7.5
tensorboard==2.0.0
tensorflow==2.0.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.0.0
ipykernel==5.1.3
ipython==7.10.2
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.3.4
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.6.1
```

Here I put the complete script as well as the STDOUT of the execution:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

nn_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

nn_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

nn_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)

nn_model.evaluate(x_test,  y_test, verbose=2)
```

> (tf2) ➜  tensorflow2 python mnist_test.py  2020-01-03 10:46:10.854619:
>   I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:145] This TensorFlow
>   binary is optimized with Intel(R) MKL-DNN to use the following CPU
>   instructions in performance critical operations:  SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
>   AVX2 FMA To enable them in non-MKL-DNN operations, rebuild TensorFlow
>   with the appropriate compiler flags. 2020-01-03 10:46:10.854860: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:115] Creating new
>   thread pool with default inter op setting: 8. Tune using
>   inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance. Train on 60000
>   samples Epoch 1/5 60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s
>   102us/sample - loss: 0.3018 - accuracy: 0.9140 Epoch 2/5 60000/60000
>   [==============================] - 6s 103us/sample - loss: 0.1437 -
>   accuracy: 0.9571 Epoch 3/5 60000/60000
>   [==============================] - 6s 103us/sample - loss: 0.1054 -
>   accuracy: 0.9679 Epoch 4/5 60000/60000
>   [==============================] - 6s 103us/sample - loss: 0.0868 -
>   accuracy: 0.9729 Epoch 5/5 60000/60000
>   [==============================] - 6s 103us/sample - loss: 0.0739 -
>   accuracy: 0.9772 10000/1 - 1s - loss: 0.0359 - accuracy: 0.9782 (tf2)
>   ➜  tensorflow2

Comment: Have you tried checking how much memory of your machine is being used ? May be it dies because it runs short of memory.

Comment: @YOLO Just before calling the line nn_model.fit(..) it uses 180MB of RAM, and then it dies. My Mac has 16GB of RAM so I don't think it comes from there...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After trying different things I run jupyter notebook on debug mode by using the command:

```
jupyter notebook --debug
```

Then after executing the commands on my notebook I got the error message:

> ```
> OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5.dylib, but found libiomp5.dylib already initialized.
> OMP: Hint This means that multiple copies of the OpenMP runtime have been linked into the program. That is dangerous, since it can
> degrade performance or cause incorrect results. The best thing to do
> is to ensure that only a single OpenMP runtime is linked into the
> process, e.g. by avoiding static linking of the OpenMP runtime in any
> library. As an unsafe, unsupported, undocumented workaround you can
> set the environment variable KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE to allow the
> program to continue to execute, but that may cause crashes or silently
> produce incorrect results. For more information, please see
> http://www.intel.com/software/products/support/.
> ```

And following [this](https://github.com/openai/spinningup/issues/16) discussion, installing nomkl on the virtual environment worked for me.

```
conda install nomkl
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach, in my case I had to copy cuDNN dll files to CUDA bin folder, and the problem is resolved

Answer (score 2):

Try `conda install nomkl` . Even if you face the problem , Check your `anaconda/lib folder`, run `ll lib*omp*`, do you see some old `libiomp5.dylib` file? Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't exactly guess the problem you are having but looks like it has do with some version clash. Do the following (that's what I did and it works for me):

1. `conda create -n tf2 python=3.7 ipython ipykernel`
2. `conda activate tf2`
3. `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow`
4. `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=tf2`
5. Run the model again and see if it is working.

Comment: I did it and I still have the same issues. Able to run from the terminal but not via jupyter notebook

Comment: Did you check this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9829

Comment: Instead of tensorflow, try with actual keras: `conda install -c conda-forge keras`

Comment: I didn't find something that worked for me on that link, but I made it work differently. I will post the steps on the answer sections now. Basically I run jupyter notebook on a debug mode to get more info on what was going on

Answer (score 1):

Find out that my problem was with zlib.dll file found in this nvidia link [Nvidia cudnn docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#install-zlib-windows)

How I fixed it:

This is for 64bit.
That is the system I'm working on

- Download file :
  64 bits - http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/zlib123dllx64.zip
- Extract the content of zlib123dllx64\dll_x64 to
  C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin\

For 32 bits systems should be similar

Answer (score 1):

For those who are stuck on this problem, I've read lots of posts, and finally found this is a problem of environment, this is what you should do(in mac):

1.change your environment
just go to your terminal(shell), type `conda activate`
it should create a new environment as you can see brakets in your bash.

2.install tensorflow
type   `conda install tensorflow`
in your terminal(shell).
Restart your kernel in jupyter notebook.this should work.

3.Reinstall numpy (if needed)
If you encounter any problem in step 2, just type `conda uninstall numpy` and `conda install numpy` in terminal(shell)

4.upgrade numpy (if needed)
If you still got problem after step 3, just type `pip install --upgrade numpy` in terminal(shell)

These steps should fix this problem.

If you want to get out of this environment, just type `conda deactivate` in terminal(shell).

Comment: Now, i am getting "500 internal server error" whenever I open any file.

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue was happening, **as show below near to red arrow**
After dubugging in jupyter, I realised this issue happens when its streaming serializaed data from tensorboard directory. Now If I change the model_dir="someothername" then I works like charm.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Installing nomkl fixed it for me.

Try `conda install nomkl` or install from *environments* in **anaconda navigator**.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow GPU won't support for versions of 12.0 and higher, use

```
import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
```